# MySQL delete join on multiple tables all matching records

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a delete join that deletes from 2 tables, but currently it is only matching and delete the first record in one of the join tables:

```
delete srid, rid from sub_region as srid
join statistics s
on srid.sub_region_id = s.sub_region_id
join region as rid
on rid.region_id = s.region_id
where s.region_id = 1;

region table:
id, region
1   america
2   mexico
3   canada

sub_region table:
id, sub_region
1   texas
2   new york

statistics table:
id, region_id, sub_region_id, text_description
1   1          1              texas has pretty good bbq
2   1          2              new york is a concrete jungle
```

My query will:
1) remove both records in the statistics table (because I have a foreign key on region and sub_region which cascades on delete)
2) remove region from region table matching the region_id
3) only removes 1 record from sub_region table

I need the query to remove all sub_regions if it is matched again the region_id in the statistics table.

Any thoughts appreciated.

SQL:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `region`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `region` (
  `region_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `region` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`region_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `region_id_UNIQUE` (`region_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `region_UNIQUE` (`region` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sub_region`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub_region` (
  `sub_region_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_region` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sub_region_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `sub_region_id_UNIQUE` (`sub_region_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `sub_region_UNIQUE` (`sub_region` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `statistics`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statistics` (
  `statistics_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `region_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `sub_region_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `text_description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`statistics_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `statistics_id_UNIQUE` (`statistics_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_region_statistics_idx` (`region_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_sub_region_statistics_idx` (`sub_region_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_region_statistics`
    FOREIGN KEY (`region_id`)
    REFERENCES `region` (`region_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sub_region_statistics`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sub_region_id`)
    REFERENCES `sub_region` (`sub_region_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please replace source data in table form with their CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And show desired final data state.

Comment: @Akina added sql to create table

Comment: Just to observe that these are sometimes referred to as countries and states/provinces

Answer (score 0):

You must disable foreign key checks before delete to achieve desired result.

```
SET @@foreign_key_checks := 0;

DELETE region, sub_region
FROM statistics
JOIN region USING (region_id)
JOIN sub_region USING (sub_region_id)
WHERE region_id = 1;

SET @@foreign_key_checks := 1;
```

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXg3ijx5TaPHRksC2TR34Y/1)

Comment: I was able to achieve the same with a transaction too. What are your thoughts on that approach ?